# MarkLogic Journal Size Parameter

Tags: marklogic

I have a question about "Journal Size" parameter in MarkLogic.
The default setting is 2GB, is this means Journal directory inside
Forests directory will never exceed 2GB?
(I could not find max journal size or number or journals parameters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the max size of a single journal file inside the `Journals` directory. Each in-memory stand comes with its own journal file to replay what was written to the in-memory stand in case of mishap. It therefor limits how much you can update in a single transaction. If you run out of journal space (e.g. exceed the max size for the active journal file), the transaction will fail.

Journal files should be cleaned up once in-memory stands are written to disk successfully. Normally, there is only one in-memory stand within each forest.

HTH!